# Does Indonesia (Bali) still offer free visa-free entry for Australian citizens?

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, indonesia, bali

I came across multiple conflicting claims regarding visiting Bali short-term with an Australian passport,

1. Visa-on-arrival is available for Australian citizens - costs US$35, and is valid for 30 days with a possible extension.

   - [Bali Visa for Australian Citizens - Australia passport](https://bali.com/bali/bali-visa-indonesia-entry-regulations/bali-visa-for-australia-passport/)
   - [Indonesia Travel Advice & Safety | Smartraveller](https://www.smartraveller.gov.au/destinations/asia/indonesia)
   - [Read Before You Leave – Bali | Travel Insider](https://www.qantas.com/travelinsider/en/explore/asia/indonesia/bali/what-to-know-before-you-go-to-bali.html)
2. Visa-on-arrival is available for Australian citizens, but the fee is waived for the Australian citizens.

   - [Indonesian Visa Fee Finally Removed for Australian Tourists](https://www.indochinaodysseytours.com/news/indonesian-visa-fee-removed-for-australians.html)
3. Australian citizens can enter Indonesia visa-free, if they intend to stay for less than 30 days. **(my preferred option)**

   - [Indonesia Visa for Australian Citizens | Indonesia Visa](https://www.indonesiaevisas.com/visa-requirements/australian-citizens)
   - [Free visa exemption | Baliviza.com](https://baliviza.com/free-visa-exemption)
   - [Australian Indonesian Association of Victoria - Travel Tips](https://www.aiav.org.au/Travel-Tips)

Obviously the best advice would be from the Indonesian government, but somehow [their website appears to be down](https://www.imigrasi.go.id/en/) at the time of writing. And while $35 is no big deal, there seems to be a lot of conflicting information on whether it is due.

---

I wonder if Indonesia (Bali) still offers free visa-free entry for Australian citizens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of October 2022, **only ASEAN nationals are entitled to enter Indonesia without a visa**.  Everybody else has to queue up and fork out 500,000 rupiah (approx US$35) for a visa on arrival, or sort out a visa in advance.  Source: [Indonesian embassy to Switzerland](https://kemlu.go.id/bern/en/news/17810/entering-indonesia-updated-on-27-april-2022), which defeats Indonesian bureaucracy through Swiss efficiency.

Indonesia used to have a much wider visa-free program, but these were all cancelled during COVID and have not been reinstated.

Comment: I'd also note that Indonesia still has a mask mandate, which might be a surprise for someone traveling from Australia.

Comment: @JonathanReez not only that, you also have to present the health app when entering malls and such.

Comment: @NeanDerThal Both requirements are largely theoretical, I didn't even bother installing the app on my last Indo trip and it was checked precisely zero times. YMMV.

Comment: Oh and masks are not enforced either? Then disregard my previous comment!

Comment: OP here, how ironic that I am now next to Switzerland and Lichtenstein, and the Indonesian mission to these countries cuts through bureaucracy as if it's cheese! Thanks

Comment: @tabdiukov Please accept the answer if it worked for you!